# Why is my PAC1934 voltage/current sensor showing lower voltage?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, monitor

I'm testing out a [PAC1934 click](https://www.mikroe.com/pac1934-click) voltage/current meter and am getting weird results.
The PAC1934 board is connected to an ESP32 development board, from which it gets 3V3 power and I2C control.
There are two supplies hooked up to the sense inputs (+) and outputs. One is 9.10V (Channel 4) and the other is 5.15V (Channel 1). Both voltages are confirmed by other measuring devices. All grounds are common.

```
U | 5V  ----|         |--- 3V3 ---|           |
S | TX  ----|  ESP32  |--- GND ---|           |
B | RX  ----|         |--- SDA ---|  PAC1934  |-- GND
  | GND ----|_________|--- SCL ---|___________|
                                    |5V| |9V|
```

Unfortunately, my readings are approx. 0.5V off and Channels 2, 3 should be zero.
Here's an example of the readings:

```
Read start:
 Voltage1    (mV) = 4610.35
 Voltage2    (mV) = 293.95
 Voltage3    (mV) = 268.07
 Voltage4    (mV) = 8481.93
 Vsense1     (mV) = 0.845337
 Vsense2     (mV) = 0.000000
 Vsense3     (mV) = 0.000000
 Vsense4     (mV) = 0.509644

Read start:
 Voltage1    (mV) = 4610.84
 Voltage2    (mV) = 292.48
 Voltage3    (mV) = 266.11
 Voltage4    (mV) = 8490.23
 Vsense1     (mV) = 0.770569
 Vsense2     (mV) = 0.000000
 Vsense3     (mV) = 0.000000
 Vsense4     (mV) = 0.624084
```

Why are the voltages lower on the 5V/9V channels, and non-zero on the unconnected channels? What could be causing the discrepencies?

Edit:
These are the raw readings:

```
Read start:
 VoltageRaw1    (mV) = 9435
 VoltageRaw2    (mV) = 579
 VoltageRaw3    (mV) = 523
 VoltageRaw4    (mV) = 17594
 VsenseRaw1     (mV) = 502
 VsenseRaw2     (mV) = 1501
 VsenseRaw3     (mV) = 1501
 VsenseRaw4     (mV) = 440

Read start:
 VoltageRaw1    (mV) = 9440
 VoltageRaw2    (mV) = 583
 VoltageRaw3    (mV) = 519
 VoltageRaw4    (mV) = 17481
 VsenseRaw1     (mV) = 1014
 VsenseRaw2     (mV) = 1523
 VsenseRaw3     (mV) = 1454
 VsenseRaw4     (mV) = 340
```

And this is the calculation done by the library to show Voltage(ch):

```
VbusLsb = 32000 / 65536.0;
VbusReal = (float)VoltageRaw1;  
VbusReal = VbusReal * VbusLsb; 
Voltage1 = VbusReal;
```

There is a setting for the resistance of the resistor used, but that does not have effect on voltage, rather current calculation. I think VbusLsb should be `32000 / 6553**5**.0`, but that makes little difference.

Comment: What scaling factors did you use? What are the raw values from the chip?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect raw readings.

Comment: Does the library use VBUSN or VBUSN_AVG ? And did you measure at the click board terminal block? Also, how did you connect the grounds?

Comment: I've used many PAC1934 chips and found them to be well within spec, so your errors suggest something fundamental. The values on the unused channels and probably noise due to them not being connected. I note the values on the vsense channels are close to the value of the errors you are reporting. What sense resistor values? Voltage drop across the sense resistors?

Comment: @Damien Not sure to be honest. The library is https://github.com/gannaramu/PAC193x_Arduino_Library

Comment: @Kartman I only know that they are 0.004R and seem to be the same spec as recommended by the PAC193x datasheet.

Comment: What current is flowing?

Comment: @Fid seems like it doesn't use the averaging. Have you tried using Mikroe's library? https://github.com/MikroElektronika/PAC1934_click

Comment: @Kartman At the time of the above readings, about 0.02A across the 9V line and 0A on the 5V line.

Comment: @Damien The library I posted has the definitions for the AVG addresses as well, I'll try editing the code to read from them.